# How to fix declarations in Android Studio blockchain app

Tags: java, android, blockchain

Found a tutorial online for building a simple blockchain app on android studio but when I finished it has key missing declarations which are coming up as unused. My capabilities allow me to resolve most minor errors through the Run and Logcat monitors while debugging but a series of stacked issues like this seems to pose too large of an issue. Here are the pages that it specifies as missing declarations:

BlockChainManager

```js
package com.example.blockchain.managers;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.example.blockchain.adapter.BlockAdapter;
import com.example.blockchain.models.BlockModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BlockChainManager {

    private final int difficulty;
    private final List<BlockModel> blocks;
    public final BlockAdapter adapter;



    public BlockChainManager(int difficulty, @NonNull Context context) {

        this.difficulty = difficulty;

        blocks = new ArrayList<>();
        BlockModel block = new BlockModel(0,System.currentTimeMillis(),null,"Genesis Block");
        block.mineBlock(difficulty);
        blocks.add(block);

         adapter = new BlockAdapter(blocks,context);
    }


    public BlockModel newBlock(String data){

        BlockModel latestBlock = lastestBlock();
        return  new BlockModel(latestBlock.getIndex()+1,System.currentTimeMillis(),latestBlock.getHash(),data);


    }


    private BlockModel lastestBlock() {

        return  blocks.get(blocks.size()-1);

    }

    public  void addBlock(BlockModel block){

        if (block!= null){
            block.mineBlock(difficulty);
            blocks.add(block);
        }

    }

    private boolean isFirstBlockValid(){

        BlockModel firstBlock = blocks.get(0);
        if (firstBlock.getIndex()!=0){

            return false;

        }

        if (firstBlock.getPreviousHash()!=null){

            return  false;

        }

        return firstBlock.getHash()!=null &&
                BlockModel.calculateHash_detail(firstBlock).equals(firstBlock.getHash());
    }

    private boolean isValidNewBlock(@Nullable BlockModel newBlock, @Nullable BlockModel previousBlock){

        if (newBlock!=null && previousBlock!= null){

            if (previousBlock.getIndex()+1!=newBlock.getIndex()){

                return  false;

            }

            if (newBlock.getPreviousHash()==null || !newBlock.getPreviousHash().equals(newBlock.getData())){

                return  false;

            }

            return  newBlock.getHash()!=null &&
                    BlockModel.calculateHash_detail(newBlock).equals(newBlock.getHash());

        }

        return false;

    }

    public boolean isBlockChainValid(){

        if (!isFirstBlockValid()){
            return  false;

        }
        for (int i = 1 ; i<blocks.size();i++){

            BlockModel currentBlock = blocks.get(i);
            BlockModel previousBlock = blocks.get(i-1);
            if (!isValidNewBlock(currentBlock,previousBlock))
                return  false;

        }

        return  true;

    }

}
```

BlockModel

```js
package com.example.blockchain.models;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class BlockModel {

    private int index,nonce;
    private long timestamp;
    private String hash,previousHash,data;

    public BlockModel(int index, long timestamp, String previousHash, String data) {
        this.index = index;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.previousHash = previousHash;
        this.data = data;
        nonce = 0;
        hash = BlockModel.calculateHash_detail(this);


    }

    public static String calculateHash_detail(BlockModel blockModel) {

        if (blockModel!= null){

            MessageDigest messageDigest;
            try{

                messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");


            }

            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
                return null;
            }

            String txt = blockModel.str();
            final  byte[] bytes = messageDigest.digest(txt.getBytes());
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (final byte b: bytes){

                String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & b);
                if (hex.length()==1){

                    builder.append('0');

                }

                builder.append(hex);

            }

            return builder.toString();

        }

        return null;

    }

    private String str() {

        return index + timestamp + previousHash + data + nonce;

    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public int getNonce() {
        return nonce;
    }

    public void setNonce(int nonce) {
        this.nonce = nonce;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getHash() {
        return hash;
    }

    public void setHash(String hash) {
        this.hash = hash;
    }

    public String getPreviousHash() {
        return previousHash;
    }

    public void setPreviousHash(String previousHash) {
        this.previousHash = previousHash;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void mineBlock(int difficulty){

        nonce = 0;
        while(!getHash().substring(0,difficulty).equals(addZeros(difficulty))){
            nonce++;
            hash = BlockModel.calculateHash_detail(this);


        }

    }

    private String addZeros(int difficulty) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0 ; i<difficulty; i++) {
            builder.append('0');
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }


}
```

CipherUtils

```js
package com.example.blockchain.utils;

import android.util.Base64;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;

public class CipherUtils {

    private static final String PASSWORD = "Saf fur yoU";
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "DES";

    public static String encryptIt(@NonNull String value){

        try{

            DESKeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(PASSWORD.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
            byte [] clearText = value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ALGORITHM");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key);
            return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(clearText),Base64.DEFAULT);

        }

        catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return value;

    }

    public static String decryptIt(@NonNull String value){

        try{

            DESKeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(PASSWORD.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
            byte [] encryptedPwdBytes = Base64.decode(value,Base64.DEFAULT);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ALGORITHM");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key);
            byte [] decryptedValueBytes = (cipher.doFinal(encryptedPwdBytes));
            return new String(decryptedValueBytes);

        }

        catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return value;

    }

}
```

MainActivity

```js
package com.example.blockchain;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.blockchain.fragments.PowFragment;
import com.example.blockchain.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.example.blockchain.databinding.ContentMainBinding;
import com.example.blockchain.managers.BlockChainManager;
import com.example.blockchain.managers.SharedPreferencesManager;
import com.example.blockchain.utils.CipherUtils;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ContentMainBinding viewBindingContent;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private SharedPreferencesManager prefs;
    private BlockChainManager blockChain;
    private boolean isEncryptionActivated, isDarkActivated;

    private static final String TAG_POW_DIALOG = "proof_of_work_dialog";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        prefs = new SharedPreferencesManager(this);
        isDarkActivated = prefs.isDarkTheme();
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isPowerSaveMode = false;

        if (powerManager!=null){

            isPowerSaveMode = powerManager.isPowerSaveMode();

        }
        if(isPowerSaveMode){

            isPowerSaveMode = powerManager.isPowerSaveMode();

        }else{

            if (isDarkActivated){

                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(

                        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES

                );

            }else{

                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(

                        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO

                );

            }

        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ActivityMainBinding viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        viewBindingContent = ContentMainBinding.bind(viewBinding.contentMain.getRoot());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        isEncryptionActivated = prefs.getEncryptionStatus();
        viewBindingContent.recyclerContent.setHasFixedSize(true);
        viewBindingContent.recyclerContent.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
        showProgressDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.text_creating_block_chain));

        new Thread(() -> runOnUiThread(() -> {
            blockChain = new BlockChainManager(prefs.getPowValue(),this);
            viewBindingContent.recyclerContent.setAdapter(blockChain.adapter);
            cancelProgressDialog(progressDialog);

        })).start();
        viewBindingContent.btnSendData.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void startBlockChain() {

        showProgressDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.text_mining_blocks));
        runOnUiThread(() -> {

            if (blockChain != null && viewBindingContent.editMessage.getText() != null && viewBindingContent.recyclerContent.getAdapter() != null) {
                String message = viewBindingContent.editMessage.getText().toString();

                if (!message.isEmpty()) {

                    if (!isEncryptionActivated) {

                        blockChain.addBlock(blockChain.newBlock(message));

                    } else {

                        try {

                            blockChain.addBlock(blockChain.newBlock(CipherUtils.encryptIt(message).trim()));

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                            Toast.makeText(this, "Something fishy happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }

                    viewBindingContent.recyclerContent.scrollToPosition(blockChain.adapter.getItemCount() - 1);

                    if (blockChain.isBlockChainValid()) {

                        viewBindingContent.recyclerContent.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                        viewBindingContent.editMessage.setText("");

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(this, "BlockChain Corrupted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                } else {

                        Toast.makeText(this, "Error empty data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    cancelProgressDialog(progressDialog);

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId()==R.id.btn_send_data)
            startBlockChain();
    }

    private void showProgressDialog(@NonNull String loadingMessage){

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setMessage(loadingMessage);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    private void cancelProgressDialog(@NonNull ProgressDialog progressDialog){

        if(progressDialog!=null){

            progressDialog.cancel();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1,menu);
        return  true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem checkEncrypt = menu.findItem(R.id.action_encrypt);
        checkEncrypt.setChecked(isEncryptionActivated);
        MenuItem checkTheme = menu.findItem(R.id.action_dark);
        checkTheme.setChecked(isDarkActivated);
        return  true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case  R.id.action_pow:
                PowFragment powFragment = PowFragment.newInstance();
                powFragment.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),TAG_POW_DIALOG);
                break;

            case R.id.action_encrypt:
                isEncryptionActivated = !item.isChecked();
                item.setChecked(isEncryptionActivated);
                if (item.isChecked()){

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Message Encryption ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Message Encryption OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                prefs.setEncryptionStatus(isEncryptionActivated);
                return  true;

            case R.id.action_dark:
                isDarkActivated =!item.isChecked();
                item.setChecked(isDarkActivated);
                prefs.setDarkTheme(isDarkActivated);
                    Intent intent = this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(this.getPackageName());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    return true;

            case R.id.action_exit:
                finish();
                break;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

        return  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

PoWFragment

```js
package com.example.blockchain.fragments;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;

import com.example.blockchain.R;
import com.example.blockchain.databinding.FragmentPowBinding;
import com.example.blockchain.managers.SharedPreferencesManager;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link PowFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class PowFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FragmentPowBinding viewBinding;
    private Context mcontext;
    private SharedPreferencesManager prefs;


    public PowFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static PowFragment newInstance() {

        return new PowFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {

        super.onAttach(context);
        mcontext = context.getApplicationContext();

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        viewBinding = FragmentPowBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), container, false);
        return viewBinding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        prefs = new SharedPreferencesManager(mcontext);
        viewBinding.edtSetPow.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getPowValue()));
        viewBinding.btnClose.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewBinding.btnContinue.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (dialog.getWindow() != null) {

            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        }

        return dialog;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.btn_close:
                dismiss();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_continue:
                if (viewBinding.edtSetPow.getText() != null) {

                    String pow = viewBinding.edtSetPow.getText().toString();
                    prefs.setPowValue(Integer.parseInt(pow));

                    if (getActivity() != null) {

                        Intent intent = mcontext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(mcontext.getPackageName());
                        startActivity(intent);
                        getActivity().finish();

                    } else {

                        dismiss();

                    }

                    break;

                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        viewBinding = null;
        mcontext = null;
    }

}
```

SharedPreferencesManager

```js
package com.example.blockchain.managers;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class SharedPreferencesManager {

    private final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private final SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private static final String PREFERENCES_DATA = "com.example.blockchain";
    private static final String ENCRYPTION_STATUS = "encryption_status";
    private static final String DARK_THEME = "dark_theme";
    private static final String PROOF_OF_WORK = "proof_of_work";
    public static final int DEFAULT_PROOF_OF_WORK = 2;

    public SharedPreferencesManager(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_DATA,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void setPowValue(int powValue){
        editor.putInt(PROOF_OF_WORK,powValue);
        editor.commit();

    }

    public int getPowValue(){

        return  sharedPreferences.getInt(PROOF_OF_WORK,DEFAULT_PROOF_OF_WORK);

    }

    public  void  setEncryptionStatus(boolean isActivated){

        editor.putBoolean(ENCRYPTION_STATUS,isActivated);
        editor.commit();

    }

    public  boolean getEncryptionStatus(){

        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(ENCRYPTION_STATUS,false);

    }

    public  void setDarkTheme(boolean isActivated){

        editor.putBoolean(DARK_THEME,isActivated);
        editor.commit();

    }

    public boolean isDarkTheme(){

        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(DARK_THEME,false);

    }
}
```

**If for any reason the Manifest will help:**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.blockchain">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**These errors seem to be centered around a specific class meant to integrate the BlockChain into the App FrameWork, but this has used its declarations:**

Block Adapter

```js
package com.example.blockchain.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.blockchain.R;
import com.example.blockchain.models.BlockModel;
import com.example.blockchain.viewholder.RecyclerViewHolder;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class BlockAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {

    private final List<BlockModel> blocks;
    private final Context mcontext;
    private int lastPosition = -1;

    public BlockAdapter(@Nullable List<BlockModel> blocks, @NonNull Context mcontext) {
        this.blocks = blocks;
        this.mcontext = mcontext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType,parent,false);

        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.txtIndex.setText(String.format(
                mcontext.getString(R.string.title_block_number),blocks.get(position).getIndex()
        ));
        holder.txtPreviousHash.setText(blocks.get(position).getPreviousHash()!=null ? blocks.get(position).getPreviousHash(): "Null");
        holder.txtTimestamp.setText(String.valueOf(new Date(blocks.get(position).getTimestamp())));
        holder.txtData.setText(blocks.get(position).getData());
        holder.txtHash.setText(blocks.get(position).getHash());
        setAnimation(holder.itemView,position);


    }

    private void setAnimation(View itemView, int position) {

        if (position>lastPosition){

            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mcontext,android.R.anim.fade_in);
            itemView.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;

        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return R.layout.item_block_data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return blocks == null ? 0:blocks.size();

    }
}
```

Let me know if anything else might help resolve these issues.

Here is the link to the video however the advertised "FREE" learning actually requires $30 for the source code once you realize what you have received does not work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5E_yBMt7Io&t=1s

Since I'm not an idiot I did not send someone money simply because they shared a few chopped up videos and asked for it in an email, but the lengthy 7-part series to deceive people into obligatorily purchasing after the "FREE" learning is illegal misrepresentation as well as unethically conning people interested in the fledgling blockchain technologies.

Any help is greatly appreciated!